# Overwriting Feature Layer on ArcGIS Online using ArcGIS Python API

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service, arcgis-python-api

I get a generic error "Job Failed" when using the below code to try and overwrite a feature layer on ArcGIS Online:

```
shp_fp = 'E:\folder\shapefile.shp'
feat_id = 'q3p094rupqe9vntowe98w98eyt0w'

item = gis.content.get(feat_id)
fs = item.layers[0]
fs.manager.overwrite(shp_fp)
```

I have editing privileges for the feature service. The service can be updated via ArcGIS Pro using "sharing" - "overwrite web layer" but programmatically it throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

This error message is generally received when you attempt to overwrite a service that has had its name changed in ArcGIS Online after publishing. For example, if I publish a service with the name 'A', change the name to 'B', and attempt to overwrite the service using a zipped file geodatabase/shp called 'C', the overwrite will fail.

**Try this:**

The overwrite will succeed if either the data being used to overwrite (eg a file geodatabase) or the service in ArcGIS Online has the same name as the original service. For example, If we publish a service with the name 'A', change the name to 'B', and attempt to overwrite the service using a zipped file geodatabase/shp called 'A', the overwrite will succeed.

You can find the original name of the service by navigating to the REST endpoint of the service in question.

- [Feature Layer Overwrite Error - Data Referring to Another Service](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-web-appbuilder-questions/feature-layer-overwrite-error-data-referring-to/td-p/541904)
- [How to update a hosted feature service on ArcGIS Online using the Python API for ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309685/how-to-update-a-hosted-feature-service-on-arcgis-online-using-the-python-api-for)
- [How To: Overwrite hosted feature services from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online using Python](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000023164)